# Maclaurin series of fraction

Tags: taylor-expansion

How to find $\frac{x+1}{x^2+x+1}$ maclaurin series.Tried splitting it into partial fractions but got stuck any hints?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Hint:**$$\frac{x+1}{x^2+x+1}=\frac{(x+1)(x-1)}{(x^2+x+1)(x-1)}=\frac{x^2-1}{x^3-1}=\frac{1-x^2}{1-x^3}.$$

Comment: Could you tell me what to do if I have $\frac{1}{x^2+x+1}$  and I need to find the 36th derivative?I tried writing x^36=x^3n-x^(3n+1) since this are the coeff of maclaurin series for that fraction but I dont know what to do next

Comment: @Lola This is another question. Please post it as such.